# Calculating the probability that an observation comes from either population A or B

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, gaussian-mixture-distribution, mixture-distribution

If I have two normal distributions A (mean = 0, variance = 4) and B (mean = 0, variance = 16), how can I calculate the probability that an observation with magnitude 2 comes from A?

Comment: I assume your mixture has equal weights, since you don't specify otherwise?

Comment: @StephanKolassa you are correct, apologies for leaving it out

Comment: Welcome to CV.  This is a good question for a newer learner to work on.  It is valuable to look at the different ways you can engage the question.  What form of an answer is more meaningful to you?

Comment: @EngrStudent Thank you. An example would be great but a hint or two would suffice.

Comment: Bob, there are several families of answers with many answers per family.  Computationally, you could do it in R, python, excel, or something else.  You could simulate it a hundred thousand times and look at rates.  Computationally-Analytically you could do one of Nick Cox's convolutions and get results that are equivalent to infinite samples.  Analytics/Symbolic - you could do it a number of ways with "squiggly herding" in a structure of a mathematical proof.  There are 100 ways to make an example, and hearing that gives you a start exploring the (wonderful and miraculous) landscape of stats.

Comment: `dnorm(2,0,2)` returns 0.1209854, `dnorm(2,0,4)` returns 0.08801633, so the first distribution is more likely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some Python code

```
from scipy.stats import norm
pA = norm.cdf(2.0, loc=0, scale=2) - norm.cdf(-2.0, loc=0, scale=2)
pB = norm.cdf(2.0, loc=0, scale=4) - norm.cdf(-2.0, loc=0, scale=4)
print('P(-2.0 < x < 2.0 | A) = {}'.format(pA))
print('P(-2.0 < x < 2.0 | B) = {}'.format(pB))
print('P(-2.0 < x < 2.0 | A) / P(-2.0 < x < 2.0 | B)= {}'.format(pA / pB))
```

And it's output:

```
P(-2.0 < x < 2.0 | A) = 0.6826894921370859
P(-2.0 < x < 2.0 | B) = 0.38292492254802624
P(-2.0 < x < 2.0 | A) / P(-2.0 < x < 2.0 | B)= 1.7828285701395248
```

I just ask, what's the probability I'd draw a data point within the specified value of 2.0 (two-sided). Do this for both, and take ratio. This means it's 1.78 more likely the data point belongs to A.